# Why isn't my player moving?

Tags: unity, c#

Why is my code not working?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript1 : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public Vector3 input;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start () 
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        moveSpeed = 2;
        input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        rb.AddForce(input * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got any error?

Comment: because your Move Speed isn't enough.you can test it with `moveSpeed = 50` or you can decrease `Mass in Rigidbody`.because when you multiply small float * big float = small float e.g 50 * 0.1 = 5

Comment: Little nitpick: `input` and `rb` should likely be `private` variables.

Answer (score 1):

After testing your code, the only conclusion I can come to is that you are not actually including a `Rigidbody` on your player. When we use `GetComponent<t>()`, we are referencing an *existing* component on the host `GameObject`.

Given your above code, on an object that contains a `Rigidbody`, the object moves quite clearly. I have included a recording, for reference.

[image: With a valid rigidbody, the script easily allows me to move a cube around the screen.]

---

#### Ensure your `GameObject` has a `Rigidbody` through code

You can add a simple tag to any script to force it to require a component. If said script is attached to a `GameObject` via the Inspector, the required component is added, too. You can do this with *any* `Component`; this is what it would look like if you forced your script to attach a `Rigidbody`:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class NewBehaviourScript1
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The information presented about FixedUpdate is misleading. FixedUpdate ticks at a regular rate, so unless you're changing your fixed update rate manually you won't get varying results from it - that's the whole point of a fixed update loop. Time.deltaTime returns a constant in FixedUpdate, and does not vary frame-to-frame. Also, AddForce does not specify how many units or units-per-second to move, it specifies how many Newtons of force to apply. The actual speed of movement will accelerate as the force continues to be applied, and time scaling is already built in.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that scaling an AddForce argument by time is not appropriate. You can think of this in terms of physics units: with the default ForceMode.Force, the input is in Newtons. Multiplying this by Time.deltaTime which is in seconds would give you a value measured in Newton-seconds (ie. an impulse), or mean that your Inspector parameter was measured in Newtons-per-second, neither of which is typically what we want for a basic constant force. ;)  As for consistency, FixedUpdate can be skipped, but it will never run with a different time delta, so again deltaTime is not the right tool.

Comment: @DMGregory, when put like that, that actually does make sense. I will have to investigate 'FixedUpdate' some more. I came to the conclusion that it was skipping frames when I was able to output *different* fixed delta times through the debug log in a single play test. This was several versions backs, and we were playing a game of "let's try and break physics", so perhaps we tripped a bug. Thanks for the clarification, though :)